# Atlas with Mongoku

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

Can I connect my Atlas MongoDB account with Mongoku?

Answer (score 0):

That is a resounding "Maybe"

The master branch of Mongoku lists the mongo node driver version 3.2.2 in its dependencies.  According to the folks a MongoDB, that is compatible with up to MongoDB 4.0: https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/driver-compatibility-reference#id11

If your Atlas cluster is version 4.0 or earlier, that should work fine.

If the cluster is MongoDB version 4.2, it might work for most things, but you may need to rebuild Mongoku with version 3.3 or higher of the driver in order to be fully compatible.